# Cufon dynamic resize

Tags: refresh, cufon, font-size

I'm using a dynamic CSS font resizer to increase, decrease and reset all fonts within a div :

```
$(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('.container').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('.container').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
```

But now I started using cufons and got stuck when it comes increasing the font .click() resize and Cufon.refresh().

A little help please?

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue:

```
$(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('.container').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('.container').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    Cufon.refresh();
    return false;
});
```